# Can I rent a domain name to somebody for web publishing while still retaining ownership and using other aspects of it?

Tags: domains, dns, web-development

I was wondering that is it possible to "rent" a domain for someone without losing ownership and possibility to use it for some own purposes.

What I mean is that is that if I don't myself need that domain for web publishing could I rent it to somebody else to use it for web publishing and still use it for other purposes of my own?

Comment: What are the "other purposes" for which you want to use the domain?   Email?   Other services?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Of course you can.  You would have to trust the person you are renting it to to not abuse the domain and they would have to trust you to keep your word regarding DNS.

The best way for you to do it is to change the nameservers to wherever they want but you keep control of the domain registration so that only you can edit nameservers.

I wouldn't tell the renters this, but I would never rent a domain.  Such arrangements tend to be a win for you and not for them.

You will (I assume) make some money from the renter.  If they build the domain up, it will become a more valuable asset for you, they gain nothing.  If the domain becomes popular, depending on your agreement, you may be able to increase the rent and they will be forced to pay or lose the goodwill they have created.  Depending on your agreement, you may be able to take the domain back at any time and profit from all their work.

Comment: I'm not sure what "other purposes" the OP want to use the domain for are, but setting the NS records like you suggest would preclude some other uses like email.

Comment: Hi! Great, thank you for your description. In fact, I'm in a position where I could be the one to ask a domain for rent. Since the owner isn't using it for web publishing it could be possible for me to suggest that maybe we could at least try it. And he wasn't willing to give it away. But I've got a another domain available which could the easy way out in this situation...

Answer (score 0):

You can, but you should never give them control over the domain...simply point it to their server/site yourself.  The only issue I see here is the possibility of them using their server/site for nefarious purposes and thereby implicating you by association.  That's a risk you'll have to measure worth taking or not.